# On OS X Snow leopard (10.6.8) running on MacBook Pro, Eclipse Helios beach balls when content assist is loading

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am running Eclipse Helios on my MacBook Pro running OS X Snow Leopard (10.6.8) and using it for android and Java programming. However, whenever I am using the built-in content assist in Eclipse, i.e. when Eclipse tries to load the Template Proposals for content assist, it starts beach balling for 30 seconds at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a known issue of helios, in Indigo the problem should not appear anymore, however you can try changing these settings to improve speed of content assist :

```
preferences ---> java ---> editor ---> content assist ---> advanded
```

Only check in first and second list the option:

- Java Proposals
- Template Proposals

Change the value of the timeout to 1ms.